# Getting weird ip 62cf6cb1-c205-4a36-9c5d-be2e1524ea29.local in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ip

I have an application in Laravel, which store client's local IP address in the database. If database IP matches clients IP it will allow login. Until now my IP was save like `192.168.1.2` in the db but now it register my IP address as `62cf6cb1-c205-4a36-9c5d-be2e1524ea29.local`. What could be the issue?

Code for login controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/user/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code that you are using.

Comment: code added for controller.